# Saxon php xml schema validation with entity reference

Tags: php, xml, xsd, saxon, saxon-c

I'm developing a php application with saxon c api EE edition which need to validate xml files against xsd schema.

i'm getting the below error when i do the validation.

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:**path**/temp.xml; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 48; The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared`

my xml file content is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE section [
<!ENTITY % ent1 SYSTEM "isonum.ent">
]>
<section>
    <section-heading>This is a test Heading &nbsp; and &amp; check</section-heading>
    <section>
        <section-heading>Another sub section heading with &nbsp; and &amp; check</section-heading>
        
    </section>
</section>
```

there is a reference in the xml for a entity file `isonum.ent` which is plased in the same path where xml file is in.

the entity file has definition for

```
<!ENTITY rdquo  "&#x201D;" ><!--=double quotation mark, right-->
<!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;" ><!--=no break (required) space-->
<!ENTITY shy    "&#173;" ><!--=soft hyphen-->
```

my php code for validation is below

```
    $proc = new Saxon\SaxonProcessor(true);
    $proc->setConfigurationProperty("xsdversion", "1.1");
    $proc->setConfigurationProperty("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/validationWarnings", "true");
    $proc->setConfigurationProperty("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/multipleSchemaImports", "on");

    $val = $proc->newSchemaValidator();
    $val->registerSchemaFromFile($xsd_path);
    $val->setProperty("report-node", "true");    
    $val->setProperty("verbose", "true");
    $val->validate($xml_path);
```

I referred the documentation available in https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation/index.html and also the samples provided with the library download zip but could identify the solution..

How can i mention the the Schema validator where to look for the entity files.
And also is possible to get all the errors at once, because in this case the validation returned only one `&nbsp;` issue where as there are two `&nbsp;`'s in the file.

Comment: Hi, To get all the errors at once have you tried using the method `getValidationReport()`? To use this method you also need to switch on the reporting: validator.setProperty('report', 'true'). See: https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation/index.html#!api/saxon_c_php_api/saxon_c_php_schemavalidator

Comment: The entity files should be picked up using the CWD, relative to the XML document.

Comment: You could also try setting the cwd with $proc->setcwd($somepath)

Comment: still the same error. i set the path like $proc->setcwd('/var/www/html/xl-val/storage/app/temp'); inside the `temp` dir the xml and ent files available

Comment: Ok I have created a bug issue for this. See: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5022 I will try to reproduce it at my end. Thanks

Comment: Hi @ond1, any update on this?

Comment: Hi, do you have the XSD?

Comment: I have managed to reproduce the error. Investigating it now

Comment: Hi @ond1, the same error occurs for xslt transformation using newXslt30Processor or newXsltProcessor.

Comment: As regards the question "And also is it possible to get all the errors at once?", XML parsers will generally stop parsing after they hit the first syntax error (wellformedness error). This is different from schema validation errors, where it's generally possible to continue validation and report multiple errors.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay, I need to get all the errors for schema validation only. And awaiting for the response on entity reference issue. my development is on hold until this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turns out to be a simple user error. The DTD declares a parameter entity but does not reference it, so the content of the parameter entity does not become part of the DTD. It needs to be written:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE section [
<!ENTITY % ent1 SYSTEM "isonum.ent">
%ent1;
]>
```

Comment: A simple user error caused an unnecessary issue. Even I have missed to notice that. Thank's for the support in this regard.